# Can't use PHPUnit using Docker - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (PhpStorm 2019.2)

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, phpunit, phpstorm

MySQL connection works when accessing application via machine (API endpoints are able to use MySQL), but it is not when accessing it from PHPUnit (locally).

I connected PhpStorm to Docker via TCP socket `tcp://localhost:2375`
Here's what I get after `docker ps` executes : `0.0:8083->3306/tcp   mysql`

Here's how I set up CLI interpreter:

[image]

Here's how I set up PHPUnit:

[image]

I double checked my `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=databasename
DB_USERNAME=databaseuser
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

Also double checked my `docker.compose.yml`:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./storage-db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=databasename
      - MYSQL_USER=databaseuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
    ports:
      - "8083:3306"
```

In addition I read [this article](http://webandapp.fr/blog/2017/09/where-is-my-database-host/) and every StackOverflow question related to this error. And yet I still get it after trying `User::all()` within test

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname
```

This is how my project structure looks:

```
dockerProject
   /docker/
     /nginx/
        nginx.conf
     /php-fpm/
        Dockerfile
   /server/ (<--Laravel project)
   docker-compose.yml
```

I am frustrated, what else I can do to make it work?

**UPDATE**
This is whole `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./storage-db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=databasename
      - MYSQL_USER=databaseuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
    ports:
      - "8083:3306"

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
     - .:/application
     - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
     - "8081:80"

  php-fpm:
    build: docker/php-fpm
    container_name: php-fpm
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - ./server:/application
    #  - .:/application
      - ./docker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

Comment: Can you post the entire docker-compose file

Comment: Yes, I did it, sir

Comment: I think you may need to put your `mysql` as a dependency for `webserver` .. so when PhpStorm launches that container it will bring up DB one as well. E.g. see these threads: 1) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000022599/comments/360000027019 2) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207941849-2016-3-EAP-Docker-linked-services-

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207941849-2016-3-EAP-Docker-linked-services-?flash_digest=c42eb25eddabb19d9233f78e65905d54b2b3b516 her is the solution for me. I find docker-compose network name and set it as shown on screenshot
[phpstorm phpunit docker settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtkvY.png)

Comment: any update ? @LizardDerad

Comment: @mik3fly-4steri5k nope, I abandoned this project after lauching laravel and executing `php artisan serve` phpunit then works. I was too frustrated to finish and rage quit, but maybe I'll finish it one day.

Comment: So I know this is really old but did you by chance run the tests outside of the docker container? I had this issue but realized I was running phpunit outside of it. As soon as I ran it inside, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what worked for me.

1. Get network name with `docker network ls`
2. Edit docker container setting : [image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the previous answer, for me using not the docker compose network but the `host` network shown by `docker network ls` did the trick:

```
NETWORK ID     NAME            DRIVER    SCOPE
...
f63abee19ca2   host            host      local
```

1. File > Settings > PHP > Test Frameworks > Your remote interpreter > In Docker container line click the directory symbol
2. In network mode add `host`.

`--net="host"` should appear under `Docker container`

[image: Docker Test Framework Docker network configuration]